# Permission Denial in android while working with camera

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera

I am newbie to native android development. I am working on `android studio`. I have a `tabbed activity` in which i am using 2 tabs. In one tab there is a map with marker on gps location of the user. The second tab is to take picture and then to save it in the storage provided by the OS. For this i followed this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798303/6854117), run the app on my device but it's crashes. I am running it on `Marshmallow`. Below is the error i get

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity } from ProcessRecord{e8f9820 15070:com.example.accurat.faisal/u0a228} (pid=15070, uid=10228) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3181)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1541)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4298)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompatJB.java:30)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:146)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:937)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:1047)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:954)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:943)
                                                                                at com.example.accurat.faisal.Camera$1.onClick(Camera.java:51)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I searched it and found that i should ask permission for it so i followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365827/6854117) and tried to add permission check like as bellow

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check permission for CAMERA
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Check Permissions Now
                // Callback onRequestPermissionsResult interceptado na Activity MainActivity
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        MainActivity.REQUEST_CAMERA);


            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );
        }
    });
```

But i am getting `red text` of `CAMERA` and `REQUEST_CAMERA`. Though i have imported them as well but still the red text is showing

```
import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
import static android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
```

Below is my manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.accurat.faisal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

I don't know what is the problem and don't know the solution and i am stuck to it.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Like the string "red text" literally? Try to clean and rebuild. Then re-install app on device.

Comment: @Fildor i have added `import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;` and it's not showing me any red lines but on `REQUEST_CAMERA`

Comment: Ahhh, so I guess there is no REQUEST_CAMERA defined in your MainActivity ... The IDE should provide some error text there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add permission check in your code and based on user action of accecpt or denial should show the camera preview [Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Also, you need to ask user permission for `android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` if you are creating a file which will be used as an input for image(captured via camera).

Comment: This should be a comment !

Comment: I know i have to add the permission check, and i am implementing it, and it's shown in my question. The problem is that i am getting `red text` for `CAMERA` and `REQUEST_CAMERA`.

Comment: @faisal1208 you forgot the else code in onclick listener.